# SQL Server: expression in "IN" operator

Tags: sql-server, database

I have table of shops name, ID, Type,etc. Also I have classes of shops (supermarkets, store, retailer) and each class has several types (supermarket = megamarket, multimarket, etc) I would like to get all shops which are supermarkets. Let's assume supermarkets is ShopClass 2.

So I would like to write query like this:

```
SELECT ShopID, ShopName 
FROM Shops 
WHERE ShopType in (SELECT ShopType FROM ShopClasses WHERE ShopClass = 2)
```

But unfortunately that query doesn't work:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

What is the reason? AFAIK I can use expressions in IN statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ShopID, ShopName 
FROM Shops AS shopslist 
WHERE shopslist.ShopType in (SELECT ShopType FROM ShopClasses WHERE ShopClass = 2)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now. Quite strange, but that is the exact solution.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!